# How to solve IoC exception when trying to use DesignTime support in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro, design-time

For some reason when trying to use the design time support in Caliburn.Micro there occurs an IoC exception.

> bei Caliburn.Micro.IoC.<.cctor>b__1(Type service)    bei
>   Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.<.cctor>b__2(Type viewType)    bei
>   Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.<.cctor>b__9(Type modelType,
>   DependencyObject displayLocation, Object context)    bei
>   Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.<.cctor>b__a(Object model, DependencyObject
>   displayLocation, Object context)    bei
>   Caliburn.Micro.View.OnModelChanged(DependencyObject targetLocation,
>   DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    bei
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    bei
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)    bei
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)    bei
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue,
>   OperationType operationType)    bei
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Boolean preserveCurrentValue)    bei
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange)    bei
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue,
>   Boolean isASubPropertyChange)    bei
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)    bei
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt
>   attempt)    bei
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(Boolean
>   lastChance)    bei MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(Boolean
>   lastChance)    bei MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(Object arg)
>   bei MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    bei
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()    bei
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    bei
>   System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()

I want to enable DesignTime support as documented [here](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/design-time) for my Window that contains a single ContentControl:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MyShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Test.DesignData.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:DesignShellViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
        cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">


    <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" />

</Window>
```

Which is used at runtime with the following ViewModel:

```
public class MyShellViewModel : ShellViewModel // derrived from own base class
{
    public MyShellViewModel(IThemeManager themeManager)
        : base(themeManager)
    {
    }
}
```

but the view should bind against this ViewModel at design time in the namespace DesignData:

```
public sealed class DesignShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public DesignShellViewModel()
    {
        AssemblySource.Instance.Add(this.GetType().Assembly);

        this.ActivateItem(new TestViewModel());
    }
}
```

This is a simple conductor containing a single sreen (a TestViewModel)
in the Test.DesignData namespace:

```
public class TestViewModel : Screen
{
// nothing interesting to see here
}
```

and corresponding view

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.DesignData.Views.TestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">It's working at design time!</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Anyone who knows what the problem might be?

**Edit: Posts by mvermef brought me closer to a solution (I think)**

Now appears a message that Caliburn is unable to find the View for the ViewModel (like it did at runtime, when name is wrong or class not found/missing... but it is there in the same library).

Here is a part of my *Bootstrapper* as asked by @mvermef:

```
// nothing special here, is empty... just a concrete class to create it via Xaml
public class Bootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShell>
{
}

// contains the important parts (Autofac, MEF integration etc.)
public class Bootstrapper<TViewModel> : BootstrapperBase
{
    // I use Common.Logging
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Bootstrapper<TViewModel>));

    // the Autofac container
    private IContainer container;

    static Bootstrapper()
    {
        // Redirect the default log output of Caliburn and use Common.Logging instead
        Caliburn.Micro.LogManager.GetLog = type => new CommonLoggingAdapter(type);
    }

    protected Bootstrapper()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var catalogs = new List<ComposablePartCatalog>();

        // Register basic services required by Caliburn
        builder.RegisterType<WindowManager>()
            .As<IWindowManager>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>()
            .As<IEventAggregator>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        if (Execute.InDesignMode)
        {
            // code that follows next should not execute in Design Mode, so I jump over (thanks to mvermev, the Exception is gone because of this => but still the problem with the missing View)
            return;
        }
        ...
    }

    protected TInstance Get<TInstance>(string key = null)
    {
        return (TInstance)this.GetInstance(typeof(TInstance), key);
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        if (Execute.InDesignMode)
        {
            return base.GetInstance(service, key);
        }

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)
                   ? this.container.Resolve(service)
                   : this.container.ResolveNamed(key, service);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return Execute.InDesignMode
                   ? base.GetAllInstances(service)
                   : this.container.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(service)) as IEnumerable<object>;
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        if (Execute.InDesignMode)
        {
            base.BuildUp(instance);
        }
        else
        {
            this.container.InjectProperties(instance);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DisplayRootViewFor<TViewModel>();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        foreach (var assembly in base.SelectAssemblies())
        {
            yield return assembly;
        }

        yield return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        yield return typeof(TViewModel).Assembly;
    }

   // other methods are only executed at runtime / not design time relevant
}
```

**Edit 2: SOLVED!** Need to add the DesignTime View assembly to the SelectAssemblies method of the Boostrapper. Bootstrapper and Views are not in the same Assembly (in my case).

```
    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        foreach (var assembly in base.SelectAssemblies())
        {
            yield return assembly;
        }

        yield return typeof(MyDesignTimeView).Assembly; // !!!IMPORTANT!!!
        yield return Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        yield return typeof(TViewModel).Assembly;
    }
```

Comment: What container are you using?

Comment: looking at what you posted, and answer for my previous post and the Bootstrapper is ideal information for best possible answer

Comment: @mvermef Autofac, but the bootstrapper is in the app assembly. The window/usercontrols and viewmoddels are in a separate assembly. So I assume caliburn should use the default bootstrapper

Comment: @mvermef to be precise I use autofac with mef integration but the view is in an assembly with no code dependency to the app. The app bootstrapper resolves at runtime which IShell to load. But how could Caliburn know that? I want to view the control during the design time and added no info to this about my special bootstrapper.

Comment: In the bootstrapperbase source there is some code that checks for DesignTime assuming everything is wired up.  Since the IoC is looking for that viewmodel ````d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:DesignShellViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"```` because you told it too, if it isn't in the MEF container it rolls over and starts to twitch like what you have listed above for error code.

Comment: @mvermef I posted the relevant parts of my Bootstrapper class. Now i see the message that the view can't be found as Textblock.

Comment: @mvermef solved the problem by adding the designtime views to selectedAssemblies()... post your suggestion as answer and I'll accept this because you took me on the right path to look into the Boostrapper

Comment: glad you figured it out :)  just do a pre-processor around the designtime items to not include them in production builds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you use the Override for SelectedAssemblies, that is how Caliburn finds other items like views/viewmodels that you are requiring, regardless of being a referenced assembly, especially if you are using MEF as the container. –